# URL List Comparison for Redirection

Tags: python, mysql, bash, .htaccess, csv

I was given 2 CSV files, with upwards of 3000+ URL's contained in each.

What I am tasked with is to create a .htaccess "redirection" chunk from "old site" to "new site", and rather than go through and manually compare them, I thought I could simply either try a bash/python script, or import them into MySQL to do the comparisons.

So, in Bash I tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {gsub(/\/$/, ""); $NF=tolower($NF)} NR==FNR{a[$NF]=$0; next} $NF in a {print a[$NF] " " $0 > "combined.csv"}' oldsite.csv newsite.csv
```

However, it returns me an empty "combined.csv", so I thought maybe "Python"... but alas, I know very little about Python, so then I thought MySQL... if I just import each CSV into a new table, I could run a comparison SQL statement and dump the results out to a 2 column new table...  alas again, I am not really sure where to begin with the comparison, figuring on a `LIKE` comparison statement, but what I am wondering here is what would the "best" (meaning most accurate comparison) method be...  and if Python, how?

***CSV SAMPLES***

**NEW URLS**

```
"new-url"
"/product/dangle-hoop-earrings-for-girls-with-cz-and-heart-dangle-in-14k-gold/"
"/product/dangle-hoop-earrings-for-girls-with-cz-and-butterfly-dangle-in-14k-gold/"
"/product/petite-lever-back-earrings-for-little-girls-in-14k-yellow-gold-with-blue-topaz-high-end-childrens-earrings/"
```

**OLD URLS**

```
"old-url"
"/product/0903-HUGGIEGK/Dangle-Hoop-Earrings-for-Girls-with-CZ-and-Heart-Dangle-in-14K-Gold/"
"/product/0954-HUGGIEGK/Dangle-Hoop-Earrings-for-Girls-with-CZ-and-Butterfly-Dangle-in-14K-Gold/"
"/product/10049Y4JBT/Petite-Lever-Back-Earrings-for-Little-Girls-in-14K-Yellow-Gold-with-Blue-Topaz---High-End-Childrens-Earrings/"
```

**EXPECTED COMBINED**

```
"old-url", "new-url"
"/product/0903-HUGGIEGK/Dangle-Hoop-Earrings-for-Girls-with-CZ-and-Heart-Dangle-in-14K-Gold/", "/product/dangle-hoop-earrings-for-girls-with-cz-and-heart-dangle-in-14k-gold/"
"/product/0954-HUGGIEGK/Dangle-Hoop-Earrings-for-Girls-with-CZ-and-Butterfly-Dangle-in-14K-Gold/", "/product/dangle-hoop-earrings-for-girls-with-cz-and-butterfly-dangle-in-14k-gold/"
"/product/10049Y4JBT/Petite-Lever-Back-Earrings-for-Little-Girls-in-14K-Yellow-Gold-with-Blue-Topaz---High-End-Childrens-Earrings/", "/product/petite-lever-back-earrings-for-little-girls-in-14k-yellow-gold-with-blue-topaz-high-end-childrens-earrings/"
```

Comment: NOTE (mainly for me), the FQDN portion of the URL's will not end up mattering

Comment: Please edit your Q to contain 1-2 lines of sample input and the expected output from that input. Good luck.

Comment: :), yeah, will once I've get them cleaned up.   While technically, there's only 3000+ unique URL's in them, that isn't counting for the API urls, the images, the stylesheets, etc...

Comment: URLs have a set of rules that define what characters can be included in them. That you have 3000+ shouldn't matter. find the 2-3 most complicated and add them (and their transformation) to your Q. Otherwise readers will post and answer and then you reply back, "oh yeah, uh well what about **this** type of URL" (and on and on). Good luck.

Comment: Finally, the code you have posted *looks" like it should work, or  be very close with just a little debugging, but we can't help if we can't reproduce your problem easily in our local environments.

Comment: Hence why I stated that I would ...   The code I posted when run on my machine does nothing

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. Looking at your problem now. AND just want to confirm that you have std Unix line endings (only `\n` chars)? `dos2unix file` will fix that. Good luck.

Comment: that seems to have taken care of a great bulk of this :)  thanks  Would you happen to know how I can pull out the "non-matches" into a seperate CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discovered in our comment thread, you needed to convert your data so it can be processed in `awk/unix` by removing the `\r` part of MS-DOS line-endings with

```
dos2unix file
```

which converts `file` line endings from `\r\n`  to `\n`. Note that you can call `dos2unix` with multiple filenames and each file will be processed, i.e.

```
dos2unix old.csv new.csv many_more ...
```

Here is your revised code which will create a separate file for unmatched records in the "new" file. The only correction I found needed was to change the final ouput to include the `,` char, so `print a[$NF] "," $0` .

```
#!/bin/bash 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}
  { gsub(/\/$/, "")
    # print "#dbg: FILENAME="FILENAME "\tNR="NR "\tFNR="FNR
    $NF=tolower($NF)
  }
  NR==FNR{
    a[$NF]=$0; next
  }
  {
    if ($NF in a) {
      print  a[$NF] "," $0  > "combined.csv"
    }
    else {
      print  a[$NF] "," $0  > "unmatched.csv"
    }
  }
  ' oldsite.csv newsite.csv
```

**output**

```
cat combined.csv

"/product/10049Y4JBT/Petite-Lever-Back-Earrings-for-Little-Girls-in-14K-Yellow-Gold-with-Blue-Topaz---High-End-Childrens-Earrings/","/product/dangle-hoop-earrings-for-girls-with-cz-and-heart-dangle-in-14k-gold/"
"/product/10049Y4JBT/Petite-Lever-Back-Earrings-for-Little-Girls-in-14K-Yellow-Gold-with-Blue-Topaz---High-End-Childrens-Earrings/","/product/dangle-hoop-earrings-for-girls-with-cz-and-butterfly-dangle-in-14k-gold/"
"/product/10049Y4JBT/Petite-Lever-Back-Earrings-for-Little-Girls-in-14K-Yellow-Gold-with-Blue-Topaz---High-End-Childrens-Earrings/","/product/petite-lever-back-earrings-for-little-girls-in-14k-yellow-gold-with-blue-topaz-high-end-childrens-earrings/"

cat unmatched.csv
,"new-url"
```

IHTH

Comment: Certainly did help.  A ton!  thank you very much mate.  One last...  how to get unmatched `old` ?

Comment: Did you try changing order of file args to `awk`, i.e.`awk ... new.csv old.csv` ? Be sure to hide/rename first run of files.